# Typesetting a definition

Tags: environments, mdframed

My current set up for type setting definitions is

```
\newenvironment{definition}[1][Definition:]{\begin{trivlist}                         
  \item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}]}{\end{trivlist}}
```

which produces

[image]

I don't really like this look but I don't want my definitions to look like the my physicals laws which are done in the `mdframed` package with the option `framemethod = tikz`

```
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor = gray!30,
  frametitle = Oberth effect]
  Is where the use of a rocket engine when traveling at high speed generates
  much more useful energy than one at low speed.
\end{mdframed}
```

and look like

[image]

Are there any suggestions on what I can do have the `definition` environment not be so plain but not mimic the look of the `mdframed` environment?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod = tikz]{mdframed}
\newenvironment{definition}[1][Definition:]{\begin{trivlist}                         
      \item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\begin{document}
\begin{definition}
This is a definition.
\end{definition}
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor = gray!30,
  frametitle = Oberth effect]
  Is where the use of a rocket engine when traveling at high speed generates
  much more useful energy than one at low speed.
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: At least give us some hints about the desired look :-) I am thinking about at least 20-30 possibilities right now, but I don't want to spend much time providing options that won't be useful. Are we allowed to use `tcolorbox`, for example?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I am not familiar with `tcolorbox`.  What does that offer?  I didn't have anything in particular in mind.  I was just going over my document I am still working on and noticed that the definitions don't stand out if you glance over the document.

Comment: `tcolorbox` offers also the possibility to have fancy boxes, in some aspects overlaps the functionality of `mdframed`, but in some aspects can be more flexible.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks.  I just looked over the documentation.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Some options of an endless selection (I chose to restrict the color to gray shades so to keep some consistency with the existing environment and to keep the document sober); I used `mdframed` for some examples and `tcolorbox` for others; any of the examples could have been produced with either of these two powerful packages.

First, using [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheoremstyle{defi}
  {\topsep}%
  {\topsep}%
  {\normalfont}%
  {}%
  {\bfseries}% 
  {:}%
  {.5em}%
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnote{~(#3)}}%
\theoremstyle{defi}
\newmdtheoremenv{definitioni}{Definition}
\newmdtheoremenv[
hidealllines=true,
leftline=true,
innertopmargin=0pt,
innerbottommargin=0pt,
linewidth=4pt,
linecolor=gray!40,
innerrightmargin=0pt,
]{definitionii}{Definition}
\newmdtheoremenv[
roundcorner=5pt,
innertopmargin=0pt,
innerbottommargin=5pt,
linewidth=4pt,
linecolor=gray!40,
]{definitioniii}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor = gray!30,
  frametitle = Oberth effect]
  Is where the use of a rocket engine when traveling at high speed generates
  much more useful energy than one at low speed.
\end{mdframed}

\begin{definitionii}
\lipsum[4]
\end{definitionii}
\begin{definitioni}
\lipsum[4]
\end{definitioni}
\begin{definitioniii}
\lipsum[4]
\end{definitioniii}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheoremstyle{defi}
  {\topsep}%
  {\topsep}%
  {\normalfont}%
  {}%
  {\bfseries}% 
  {:}%
  {.5em}%
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnote{~(#3)}}%
\theoremstyle{defi}
\newmdtheoremenv[
hidealllines=true,
innertopmargin=0pt,
linewidth=4pt,
linecolor=gray!40,
singleextra={
  \draw[line width=3pt,gray!50,line cap=rect] (O|-P) -- +(1cm,0pt);
  \draw[line width=3pt,gray!50,line cap=rect] (O|-P) -- +(0pt,-1cm);
  \draw[line width=3pt,gray!50,line cap=rect] (O-|P) -- +(-1cm,0pt);
  \draw[line width=3pt,gray!50,line cap=rect] (O-|P) -- +(0pt,1cm);
  },
firstextra={
  \draw[line width=3pt,gray!50,line cap=rect] (O|-P) -- +(1cm,0pt);
  \draw[line width=3pt,gray!50,line cap=rect] (O|-P) -- +(0pt,-1cm);
},
secondextra={
  \draw[line width=3pt,gray!50,line cap=rect] (O-|P) -- +(-1cm,0pt);
  \draw[line width=3pt,gray!50,line cap=rect] (O-|P) -- +(0pt,1cm);
}
]{definitioni}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor = gray!30,
  frametitle = Oberth effect]
  Is where the use of a rocket engine when traveling at high speed generates
  much more useful energy than one at low speed.
\end{mdframed}

\begin{definitioni}
\lipsum[4]
\end{definitioni}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newmdenv[
innertopmargin=0pt,
roundcorner=5pt,
linewidth=1pt,
linecolor=gray!40,
innertopmargin=\baselineskip,
singleextra={
  \node[
    anchor=west,
    xshift=7pt,
    fill=gray!20,
    rounded corners=2pt,
    draw] at (P-|O) {\bfseries Definition:};
},
firstextra={
  \node[
    anchor=west,
    xshift=7pt,
    fill=gray!20,
    rounded corners=2pt,
    draw] at (P-|O) {\bfseries Definition:};
}
]{definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor = gray!30,
  frametitle = Oberth effect]
  Is where the use of a rocket engine when traveling at high speed generates
  much more useful energy than one at low speed.
\end{mdframed}

\begin{definition}
\lipsum[4]
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And now some more options using the [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{definitioni}{
  breakable,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  title={Definition:}
}
\newtcolorbox{definitionii}{
  skin=enhanced,
  breakable,
  colback=white,
  colframe=gray!30,
  coltitle=black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  leftrule=0.5cm,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  title={Definition:}
}
\newtcolorbox{definitioniii}{
  skin=enhanced,
  breakable,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  colback=white,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  title={Definition:},
  shadow={1mm}{-1mm}{0mm}{fill=gray,opacity=0.5,sharp corners}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor = gray!30,
  frametitle = Oberth effect]
  Is where the use of a rocket engine when traveling at high speed generates
  much more useful energy than one at low speed.
\end{mdframed}

\begin{definitioni}
\lipsum[4]
\end{definitioni}
\begin{definitionii}
\lipsum[4]
\end{definitionii}
\begin{definitioniii}
\lipsum[4]
\end{definitioniii}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And another one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{definition}{
freelance,
breakable,
before=\par\vspace{2\bigskipamount}\noindent,
after=\par\bigskip,
frame code={
  \node[
  anchor=south west,
  inner xsep=8pt,
  xshift=8pt,
  rounded corners=5pt,
  font=\bfseries\color{white},
  fill=gray] at (frame.north west) (tit) {\strut Definition:};
  \draw[
  line width=3pt,
  rounded corners=5pt,gray
  ] (tit.west) -| (frame.south west) -- ([xshift=15pt]frame.south west);
},
interior code={},
top=2pt
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor = gray!30,
  frametitle = Oberth effect]
  Is where the use of a rocket engine when traveling at high speed generates
  much more useful energy than one at low speed.
\end{mdframed}

\begin{definition}
\lipsum[4]
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @dustin OK. I think I'll add some others more.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I'm not able to reproduce your various styles.  Among other things, there is no vertical white space between the examples given.  I've copied and pasted your examples and tried compiling both via `pdflatex` and through `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`.  Any ideas why my results would come out differently?

Comment: @A.Ellett perhaps different versions of `mdframed`? In my system I have `mdframed.sty    2013/07/01 1.9b: mdframed`.

Comment: @dustin I added some more options (the last three ones using `tcolorbox`).

Comment: That is great.  I will award a bounty to you when the post will let me.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I'm currently updating my TeXLive installation.  I'll see if that fixes it.

Comment: @A.Ellett there is a recent post within the last 2 days about spacing issues in `mdframed`.  It is corrected in 2013.

Comment: Updating resolved the issue.

Comment: Very nice examples!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina a thousand and some change more of those and you will be up there with egreg.