# tcolorbox: framing example problems that index in order and allow for a title as an argument

Tags: indexing, tcolorbox

I would like to take this `tcolorbox` created by Gonzalo Medina here [Typesetting a definition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124847/typesetting-a-definition)
but have each usage of the box index starting from `1, 2, ...` which allows a title input.

Currently my set up looks like:

[image]

So it says `Example Problem (number) (what the problem is about)`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{Examples}{
      breakable,
      fonttitle=\bfseries,
      title={Example Problem (indexing number here) rest of title:}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{Examples}
  \lipsum[4]
\end{Examples}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Can this something like this be done?

**Edit 1:**

Following Gonzalo Medina's first code, the first letter is being cut off in the box.

[image]

That should be Calculate not alculate.  So this was caused by having

```
\begin{examples}{Synodic Period of the Earth/Mars Orbits}
```

without `{test}`.  Does `{test}` always have to end it?

**Edit 2**

The colon wont appear after the descriptions

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage[pdfencoding = auto, psdextra, bookmarksdepth = 4]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}

\tcbset{
  theorem/.style args = {#1#2#3#4}{%                                                
    step and label = {#2}{#4},%                                                     
    title = {\mbox{#1~\csname the#2\endcsname\ }#3:}}
}
\newcounter{exa}
\tcbmaketheorem{examples}{Example Problem}{
  breakable,
  fonttitle = \bfseries,
}{exa}{ex}

\begin{document}
\begin{examples}{example}{exa:test}
  \lipsum[4]
  \par\medskip
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includestandalone{line}
    \captionof{figure}[line]{line}
    \label{line}
  \end{minipage}
\end{examples}
\cref{line}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case, you can use `\tcbmaketheorem` to define the environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{exa}
\tcbmaketheorem{Examples}{Example}{
breakable,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
}{exa}{ex}

\begin{document}
\begin{Examples}{Additional description}{test}
  \lipsum[4]
\end{Examples}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To get the exact style in the question, the theorem style can be redefined:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tcbset{
  theorem/.style args={#1#2#3#4}{%
    step and label={#2}{#4},%
    title={\mbox{#1~\csname the#2\endcsname\ }#3:}}
}
\newcounter{exa}
\tcbmaketheorem{Examples}{Example}{
breakable,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
}{exa}{ex}

\begin{document}
\begin{Examples}{Additional description}{test}
  \lipsum[4]
\end{Examples}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The syntax for `\tcbmaketheorem` is:

```
\tcbmaketheorem{<name>}{<display name>}{<options>}{<counter>}{<prefix>}
```

the meaning of the first four arguments is clear. `<prefix>`, together with the `<marker>` used in the second mandatory argument of the invocation of the environment:

```
\begin{<name>}{<additional description>}{<marker>}
content
\end{<name>}
```

will be used to produce a string for cross references having the form `<prefix>:<marker>` for cross-referencing. For example, with the settings of my example above:

```
\tcbmaketheorem{Examples}{Example}{
breakable,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
}{exa}{ex}
```

and

```
\begin{Examples}{Additional description}{test}
  \lipsum[4]
\end{Examples}
```

the declared prefix was `ex` and the particular invocation has `test` as marker, so you can cross-reference the example using `\ref{ex:test}`.

Floats are not allowed inside the environment; instead you can use a `minipage` and provide captions with the help of `\captionof` (from the `caption` or `capt-of` packages). A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}

\tcbset{
  theorem/.style args={#1#2#3#4}{%
    step and label={#2}{#4},%
    title={\mbox{#1~\csname the#2\endcsname\ }#3:}}
}
\newcounter{exa}
\tcbmaketheorem{Examples}{Example}{
breakable,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
}{exa}{ex}

\begin{document}

\begin{Examples}{Additional description}{exa:test}
\lipsum[4]\par\medskip
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a}
\captionof{figure}{the description of the image}
\label{fig:testa}
\end{minipage}\par\medskip
\lipsum[4]
\end{Examples}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Update:

With the changes introduced in `tcolorbox` version `2.40 (2013/07/15)`, the change for the style above won't produce the desired result for the title. With this version, the following code has to be used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\listfiles
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage[pdfencoding = auto, psdextra, bookmarksdepth = 4]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\def\tcb@theo@title#1#2#3{%
  \ifdefempty{#2}{\setbox\z@=\hbox{#1}}{\setbox\z@=\hbox{#1~#2}}%
  \def\temp@a{#3}%
  \ifx\temp@a\@empty\relax%
    \unhbox\z@:%
  \else%
    \setbox\z@=\hbox{\unhbox\z@\ }%
    \hangindent\wd\z@%
    \hangafter=1%
    \mbox{\unhbox\z@}#3:%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother
\newcounter{exa}
\tcbmaketheorem{examples}{Example Problem}{
  breakable,
  fonttitle = \bfseries,
}{exa}{ex}

\begin{document}
\begin{examples}{Additional description}{test}
  \lipsum[4]
  \par\medskip
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includestandalone{line}
    \captionof{figure}[line]{line}
    \label{line}
  \end{minipage}
\end{examples}
\cref{line}
\end{document}
```

### New Update:

The author of `tcolorbox` has introduced some modifications to `tcbtheorems.code.tex` in version `2.41 (2013/07/23)`, so now all the examples  in my answers work.

Comment: @dustin are you using *both* mandatory arguments for the environment? Even if you won't place anything there, you should use it and leave it empty: `\begin{Examples}{}{}...\end{Examples}`.

Comment: @dustin It will be used as a marker for cross-references. In some minutes I can add some explanations to the code; it's dinner time here ;-)

Comment: @dustin floats can't be placed inside the environment; however, you can still have figures and tables with captions: simply use a `minipage` instead of `figure` (or `table`) and `\captionof` (from the `caption` or `capt-of` packages) instead of `\caption`.

Comment: @dustin not exactly; I'll add an example in some seconds. In the meantime I've added an explanation of the use of the second mandatory argument, for labelling.

Comment: @dustin I added an example using a captioned figure; for tables, the only change is `\captionof{table}{description}`.

Comment: @dustin Sure: `\captionof{figure}[short]{the description of the image}`.

Comment: @dustin no idea. I've never used the `standalone` package. Feel free to open a fresh new question about this.

Comment: I can't get the `:` to do what your bottom code does `Example description:`  It still does Example: description`.

Comment: @dustin answer updated with the code required using the newest version of tcolorbox.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina With `tcolorbox` version `2.41 (2013/07/23)` **both** of your codes (will) work. I switched `\tcbmaketheorem` back to its old v2.33 behaviour since I considered backward compatibilty broken. Nevertheless, your new code also works with exception of `\includestandalone{line}` where a file `line.tex` seems to be missing.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm Ah, good to know; those are good news. Thanks for thinking about backward compatibility. The file `line.tex` in my answers is the same as the one given in the question, so I didn't include it in my answers.

Comment: @dustin the previous comments might be of interest for you. With the newest version of `tcolorbox`, the previous solution will again work (the newest one will also do the job).

Comment: I tried referencing an example it works but it doesn't.  I called `{soiE}` so then I referenced it as `\cref{ex:soiE}`.  The output is `?? 17`.  It is example 17 but why `??` which is indicative of a bad reference.  `Latexmk` says everything is update so the reference is good in its eyes.

Comment: @dustin You need to tell `cleveref` the new type of object you want to reference; with the code in the "Update", this is done with `\crefname{exa}{example}{examples}
\Crefname{exa}{Example}{Examples}`
.