# tcolorbox: The use of subfloats in a tcolorbox

Tags: subfloats, tcolorbox

From a previous post, I found out that I need the `capt-of` package to have figures in a `tcolorbox`.  How do I use `subfloats`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage[caption = false]{subfig}

\tcbset{
  theorem/.style args = {#1#2#3#4}{%                                                
    step and label = {#2}{#4},%                                                     
    title = {\mbox{#1~\csname the#2\endcsname\ }#3:}}
}
\newcounter{exa}
\tcbmaketheorem{examples}{Example Problem}{
  breakable,
  fonttitle = \bfseries,
}{exa}{ex}

\begin{document}
\begin{examples}{example ert}{exa:test}
  \lipsum[1]
  \par\medskip
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
      \subfloat[caption]{\includestandalone{line}} &
      \subfloat[caption]{\includestandalone{line}}
    \end{tabular}
    \captionof{figure}{caption}
  \end{minipage}
  \par\medskip
  \lipsum[2]
\end{examples}
\end{document}
```

---

```
\documentclass[convert = false]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- (0,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit 2:**

With Gonzalo Medina's code, I get

[image]

That is, no `(a)` or `(b)`.

This had to do with the option `caption = false` with `subfig`.  By removing that option, `(a)` and `(b)` appear.

Comment: I would suggest, you have a look at [caption](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) and [subcaption](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption). The `capt-of` package is then no longer necessary and `subfig` is afaik deprecated.

Comment: @Martin I know `subfigure` is deprecated but are sure `subfig` is?

Comment: Maybe not deprecated, but not developed either. The documentation dates back to 2005. More features will await you in the above mentioned packages. Particularly for subfigures I found that there are several nice commands to get them into the document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you cannot use floats inside the `tcolorbox`, `\subfloat` won't work here. Since you are already using `subfig`, you can use the `\captionof` also for subfloats; if you want the subcaptions inside the `tabular`, you'll need to wrap them in a `\parbox` (this is not necessary in other contexts):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{subfig}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=parens}

\tcbset{
  theorem/.style args = {#1#2#3#4}{%                                                
    step and label = {#2}{#4},%                                                     
    title = {\mbox{#1~\csname the#2\endcsname\ }#3:}}
}
\newcounter{exa}
\tcbmaketheorem{examples}{Example Problem}{
  breakable,
  fonttitle = \bfseries,
}{exa}{ex}

\begin{document}
As we see in Example Problem~\ref{ex:test}...
\begin{examples}{example ert}{test}
  \lipsum[1]
  \par\medskip
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c@{\hspace{2em}}c}
      \includestandalone{line} &
      \includestandalone{line} \\
\parbox{3.5cm}{\captionof{subfigure}{caption for subfigure one}} &
\parbox{3.5cm}{\captionof{subfigure}{caption for subfigure two}}
    \end{tabular}
    \captionof{figure}{caption}
  \end{minipage}
  \par\medskip
  \lipsum[2]
\end{examples}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice also that I changed the marker you were using in the last mandatory argument of `examples` so the string used for cross-referencing is simpler.

Comment: How would it be done if it wasn't enclosed in `tabular`?

Comment: Also, is `subcaption` compatible with `subfig`?  The reason I ask because if not, I will have to edit 60 pages.

Comment: @dustin Outside the `tabular` you don't need the `\parbox`, and no, `subcaption` and `subfig` are *not* compatible. However, you can simply use `subfig` instead of `subcaption` and still have your sub-captions using `\captionof`, as my updated answer shows.

Comment: @dustin the image you added to your question is *not* my code; in fact. you didn't add any code but just an image. My code does produce the labels (as the attached image shows). Please add a minimal document with the *real* code you are using and that produces that output.

Comment: It had to do with the option `caption = false` in `subfig` so I guess I can't use that option.  But I did come across something else.  This method changes the how my table of contents works.

Comment: @dustin in which way it changes it?

Comment: @dustin adding just a picture is useless. Please reduce the example to a MWE illustrating the problem and add this MWE to your question.

Comment: I was able to get it squared away.  Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @dustin Ah, OK. Glad to hear the problem was solved.

Comment: One last thing, how do you get the colon after the descriptions?  I have your exact set up and it refuses to do it.

Comment: @dustin again, without code is impossible to say. If you have my exact settings and are getting a different result, perhaps your package(s) are outdated, If not, then the settings are not exactly the same and without the code it's impossible to tell.

Comment: From our my original question on indexing it [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124854/tcolorbox-framing-example-problems-that-index-in-order-and-allow-for-a-title-as), I added an edit showing it with full code.

Comment: @dustin I see the colon there, after "Figure 1" which is the only caption in that example. Where is the problem?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9746/discussion-between-gonzalo-medina-and-dustin)

Answer (score 3):

Adding `\captionsetup{type=figure}` at the right position should help:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabu}
%\usepackage{capt-of} % -- dropped
\usepackage{subfig} % -- "caption=false" removed

\tcbset{
  theorem/.style args = {#1#2#3#4}{%                                                
    step and label = {#2}{#4},%                                                     
    title = {\mbox{#1~\csname the#2\endcsname\ }#3:}}
}
\newcounter{exa}
\tcbmaketheorem{examples}{Example Problem}{
  breakable,
  fonttitle = \bfseries,
}{exa}{ex}

\begin{document}
\begin{examples}{example ert}{exa:test}
  \lipsum[1]
  \par\medskip
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \captionsetup{type=figure} % -- added
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
      \subfloat[caption]{\includestandalone{line}} &
      \subfloat[caption]{\includestandalone{line}}
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{caption} % -- replaced by regular \caption
  \end{minipage}
  \par\medskip
  \lipsum[2]
\end{examples}
\end{document}
```

However, this needs the `subfig` option `caption=false` to be removed. Is there any particular reason why you have set this option?