# Example numbers with respect to chapters in tcolorbox title

Tags: tcolorbox

I found this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124854/tcolorbox-framing-example-problems-that-index-in-order-and-allow-for-a-title-as) which explains how to add index number to example in tcolorbox. However, I have been unable to modify it to include chapter reference numbering (e.g., Example 1.1, or 4.3, etc.). Any hints?

Comment: Please provide some basic code in the form of a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)). You are more likely to attract a useful answer that way because you have shown that you are willing to help those who would help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Updated 2015-08-29** to include a label, as requested by @Qasim.

---

Use `tcolorbox`'s `number freestyle` option along with `auto counter` and `number within=chapter`, as in the following MWE. You can also add a `label` by using an optional (first) argument to `\newtcolorbox` (the second mandatory argument will be the title).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=chapter, number freestyle={\noexpand\thechapter.\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter}}]{myexample}[2][]{%
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title=Example~\thetcbcounter: #2,
    #1
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}

\begin{myexample}[label=exfirst]{First example}
  \lipsum[4]
\end{myexample}

\begin{myexample}{Second example}
  \lipsum[4]
\end{myexample}

\chapter{Second chapter}

\begin{myexample}[label=exthird]{Third example}
  \lipsum[4]
\end{myexample}

I can now refer to example~\ref{exfirst} and example~\ref{exthird}.
\end{document}
```

**Output**:
[image: Output for above code]

---

If you would also like the title to be optional, you could use the following approach:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tcbset{mytitle/.style={title={Example~\thetcbcounter\ifstrempty{#1}{}{: #1}}}}
\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=chapter, number freestyle={\noexpand\thechapter.\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter}}]{myexample}[1][]{%
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    mytitle={},
    #1
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}

\begin{myexample}[mytitle={First example}, label=exfirst]
  \lipsum[4]
\end{myexample}

\begin{myexample}
  \lipsum[4]
\end{myexample}

\chapter{Second chapter}

\begin{myexample}[mytitle={Third example}, label=exthird]
  \lipsum[4]
\end{myexample}

I can now refer to example~\ref{exfirst} and example~\ref{exthird}.
\end{document}
```

**Output**:
[image: Output for above code]

Comment: How do I refer to different examples in this case? For example, what should be Latex code for "as shown in Example 1.2"?

Comment: @QMC `\ref{exfirst}` should give you the number for the first example assuming that you put `label=exfirst` in options the for `\begin{myexample}`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to redefine the `exa` counter to achieve what you want:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{exa}
\renewcommand\theexa{\thechapter.\arabic{exa}} 
\tcbmaketheorem{Examples}{Example}{
breakable,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
}{exa}{ex}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\begin{Examples}{Additional description}{test}
  \lipsum[4]
\end{Examples}
\end{document}
```

[image]