# Referring to example numbers in tcolorbox

Tags: cross-referencing, tcolorbox

In a [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261471/example-numbers-with-respect-to-chapters-in-tcolorbox-title) I asked before, I implemented method 2 by feculededentier. However, now I am facing difficulty in referring to different examples in this case. For example, what should be the Latex code for "as shown in Example 1.2"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to slightly change the definition. Make it 2 arguments with first one as optional:

```
\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=chapter, number freestyle={\noexpand\thechapter.\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter}}]{myexample}[2][]{%
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title=Example~\thetcbcounter: #2,
    #1
}
```

And then use the `label=<name>` key like

```
\begin{myexample}[label=second]{Second example}
```

Now you can use `Example~\ref{second}` to refer to these boxes.

Full example (taken and modified from the answer linked in the question)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=chapter, number freestyle={\noexpand\thechapter.\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter}}]{myexample}[2][]{%
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title=Example~\thetcbcounter: #2,
    #1
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}

\begin{myexample}[label=first]{First example}
  \lipsum[4]
\end{myexample}

\begin{myexample}[label=second]{Second example}
  \lipsum[4]
\end{myexample}

\chapter{Second chapter}

\begin{myexample}[label=third]{Third example}
  \lipsum[4]
\end{myexample}

From Example~\ref{second} we get some idea.

\end{document}
```

[image]

## `cleveref` version:

You can load `cleveref` package and use `crefname` in the options to reduce typing.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=chapter, 
    crefname={example}{examples},
    Crefname={Example}{Examples},
    number freestyle={\noexpand\thechapter.\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter}}]
    {myexample}[2][]{%
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title=Example~\thetcbcounter: #2,    
    #1
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}

\begin{myexample}[label=first]{First example}
  \lipsum[4]
\end{myexample}

\begin{myexample}[label=second]{Second example}
  \lipsum[4]
\end{myexample}

\chapter{Second chapter}

\begin{myexample}[label=third]{Third example}
  \lipsum[4]
\end{myexample}

\Cref{second} gives us some idea as seen from \cref{first}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not working for me. Adding #2, #1 creates the problem. The error is missing number, treated as zero.

Comment: @QasimChaudhari Are you compiling the code as such without modifying? If you still get the error, please try updating your `tcolorbox` package.

Comment: Harish, it worked very well now. Thanks! Actually I had a \vspace{2mm} immediately after starting the box, and I had headings with square brackets [ ] as answered in my previous question. I have changed these two things (put a line break after starting the box, and use { } for headings) to solve the problem.