# How to define counter for problems and examples of a text?

Tags: counters

This is the first time that I'm going to prepare a book with Latex. I am not so familiar with advanced options of Latex, and in particular with typography. The book includes a lot of examples and problems, but I don't want to write the number of each one because Latex can do it. I have attached a sample page of a book and I want to follow exactly the same style. I will appreciate it if someone helps me. For example, all examples are boxed, and all problems are in a gray box with a thick line at the bottom. The difficult problems are denoted by a star sign. Also, I want to adjust the space of items once for all (I mean, for example, the spacing between the problem and solution), so that I don't have to adjust it each time.
 [image: sample]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
\title{Quantum Mechanics}
\author{My name}
\maketitle


\chapter{Wave Function}
\section{Schrodinger equation}
I'm going to show the first example

\boxed{
Example 1.1
This is the question. Following is the solution
\textbf{Solution:} And here is the solution
}

\textbf{* Problem 1.1}
 Do the followings:

(a) Compute x.

(b) compute y.


\chapter{second}

\chapter{third}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `tcolorbox` may be a good choice for such things. It allows you to produce numbered environments that have shaded backgrounds, and much more. [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/263579/121799) is a (random) example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to give you a start. No attempt of reproducing your screen shot is made.

1. `tcolorbox` is used to create environments of the type you seem to seek. I mainly adapted them from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/263579/121799).
2. There is no need to hard-code the number of the examples, nor the items of the list. Rather, this is done by `tcolorbox` and `enumerate` in the following example. Of course, there are many more ways of producing auto-numbered environments such as theorems.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=chapter, 
    crefname={example}{examples},
    Crefname={Example}{Examples},
    number freestyle={\noexpand\thechapter.\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter}}]
    {myexample}[2][]{%
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title=Example~\thetcbcounter: #2,    
    #1
}


\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=chapter, 
    crefname={example}{examples},
    Crefname={Example}{Examples},
    number freestyle={\noexpand\thechapter.\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter}}]
    {myproblem}[2][]{%
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title=Problem~\thetcbcounter: #2,    
    #1
}

\begin{document}
\title{Quantum Mechanics}
\author{My name}
\maketitle


\chapter{Wave Function}
\section{Schr\"{o}dinger equation}
I'm going to show the first example


\begin{myexample}[label=first]{First example}
  This is the question. Following is the solution.

\textbf{Solution:} And here is the solution
\end{myexample}

\begin{myexample}[label=second]{Second example}
  \dots
\end{myexample}

\chapter{Second chapter}

\begin{myexample}[label=third]{Third example}
  \dots
\end{myexample}

\Cref{second} gives us some idea as seen from \cref{first}.

\begin{myproblem}[label=third]{}
 Do the followings:
 \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
   \item Compute $x$.
   \item Compute $y$.
 \end{enumerate}
\end{myproblem} 

\chapter{second}

\chapter{third}



\end{document}
```

And this is an example of what this gives you.

[image]

I understand that this does not reproduce your screen shot. However, I am convinced that a look in the `tcolorbox` manual will allow you to achieve these things.