# My reference to my `tcolorbox` doesn't work

Tags: tcolorbox, labels, counters, ref

I'm just trying to reference one of my example in my text but it's always labelled with the upper previous counter (here the section number).

My example environment is defined as `exmp` which are a `tcolorbox` environment itself. I know that the trouble probably comes from my `newtcolorbox` definition but I cannot find from where. If you have any idea, please tell me.

I'm working with the `pdfLaTex` compiler and here is my minimal code:

```
\documentclass[justified,notoc,numbers]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

%-----------FOR DEMO-----------
\usepackage{lipsum}

%=======================================================
%                      FONT STYLE
%=======================================================
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}

%=======================================================
%                       COUNTERS
%=======================================================
\newcounter{theexample}[section]
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
%=======================================================
%                       COLORS
%=======================================================
\definecolor{grey}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\definecolor{myColor}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 1.0}

\newtcolorbox{exmp}[1][]{
  breakable,
  enhanced,
  borderline west={2pt}{0pt}{myColor},
  sharp corners,
  boxrule=0pt,
  fonttitle={\large\bfseries},
  coltitle={black},
  title= {\textcolor{myColor}{Exemple  \stepcounter{theexample}\thesection.\arabic{theexample}:} #1\\},
  attach title to upper,
  right=0pt,
  top=0pt,
  bottom=0pt,
  frame hidden,
  colback=white!80!gray,
}



\title{test - tex.stackexchange.com}
\author[Author Name \& Firstname]{Author Name \& Firstname}


%=======================================================
%                       GEOMETRY
%=======================================================
\geometry{
  left=15mm,                    % left margin
  textwidth=140mm,              % main text block
  headsep=10mm,
  headheight = 0mm,
  marginparsep=7mm,             % gutter between main text block and margin notes
  marginparwidth=50mm,          % width of margin notes
  bottom = 1.5cm, 
  top = 1.7cm
}

%=======================================================
%                       DOCUMENT
%=======================================================
\begin{document}
\section{Chapter 1:}
\subsection{Section 1.}
[![\subsection{Section 2.}][1]][1]
\begin{exmp}[My example's title]
\label{EX1}
\lipsum[1]
\end{exmp}

Try to reference to my example counter using \texttt{ref\{EX1\}}: \ref{EX1}

\end{document}
```

So here the result is

[image: What it give]

when what I want is

[image: What I want]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Related: [How to define labels within a tcolorbox?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/231375/134144) To summarize:you might want to use `[label=yourlabeltext]` instead of the  usual `\label` command.

Comment: Probably also interesting: [Referring to example numbers in tcolorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/263577/134144)

Comment: @leandriis The trouble was that I didn't design my `tcolorbox` with an option field, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED:

The trouble was indeed with my parameters declaration, I need 2 and not 1 parameter. #1 is my option while #2 will be my title. Here is the code of the solution:

```
\documentclass[justified,notoc,numbers]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

%-----------FOR DEMO-----------
\usepackage{lipsum}

%=======================================================
%                      FONT STYLE
%=======================================================
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}

%=======================================================
%                       COUNTERS
%=======================================================
\newcounter{theexample}[section]
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
%=======================================================
%                       COLORS
%=======================================================
\definecolor{grey}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\definecolor{myColor}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 1.0}

\newtcolorbox{exmp}[2][]{
  breakable,
  enhanced,
  borderline west={2pt}{0pt}{myColor},
  sharp corners,
  boxrule=0pt,
  fonttitle={\large\bfseries},
  coltitle={black},
  title= {\textcolor{myColor}{Exemple  \stepcounter{theexample}\thesection.\arabic{theexample}:} #2\\},
  attach title to upper,
  right=0pt,
  top=0pt,
  bottom=0pt,
  frame hidden,
  colback=white!80!gray,
  #1,
}



\title{test - tex.stackexchange.com}
\author[Author Name \& Firstname]{Author Name \& Firstname}


%=======================================================
%                       GEOMETRY
%=======================================================
\geometry{
  left=15mm,                    % left margin
  textwidth=140mm,              % main text block
  headsep=10mm,
  headheight = 0mm,
  marginparsep=7mm,             % gutter between main text block and margin notes
  marginparwidth=50mm,          % width of margin notes
  bottom = 1.5cm, 
  top = 1.7cm
}

%=======================================================
%                       DOCUMENT
%=======================================================
\begin{document}
\section{Chapter 1:}
\subsection{Section 1.}
\subsection{Section 2.}
\begin{exmp}[label = EX1]{My example's title}
\lipsum[1]
\end{exmp}

Try to reference to my example counter using \texttt{ref\{EX1\}}: 1.1

\end{document}
```