# Display number in tcolorbox like the auto number in equation

Tags: numbering, tcolorbox

I want to make a tcolorbox with a number. I currently have created a new command

`\newenvironment{mybox}{\begin{tcolorbox}\centering}{\end{tcolorbox}}`

I want to display numbering inside the tcolorbox.

I find this [The first style numbering tcolorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261471/example-numbers-with-respect-to-chapters-in-tcolorbox-title), but i can not combine it with mine.

I only want to add a number in the box. 
I tried to do `\newenvironment{mybox}{\begin{tcolorbox}[within=section]\centering}{\end{tcolorbox}}`but it wont work.

and i also want to \ref the box in this way `\ref{first box}`

```
\begin{mybox}\label{first box}
      bla,bla,bla...
   \end{mybox}
```

please someone help me!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To build a numbered `tcolorbox` you should use a `\newtcbolorbox` command instead of a `\newenvironment`. This way you can use a counter within every `tcolorbox`. Take a look at section "5 Initialization Option Keys" in `tcolorbox` documentation.

Here you have an example with `mybox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=section]{mybox}[2][]{%
    title=Mybox~\thetcbcounter: #2, #1}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\begin{mybox}[label=myfirstbox]{A box with title}
This is a numbered box.
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}{}
This is a numbered box without title. Previous box was ~\ref{myfirstbox}.
\end{mybox}

\section{Second section}

\begin{mybox}{A box with title}
This is a numbered box. 
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}{}
This is a numbered box without title. First box was ~\ref{myfirstbox}.
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i want to label it use ```\label{}``` this way.

Comment: The only way to make label for box is ```[label=]``` ? i really want to use the normal label way.

Comment: What do you want to use `\label`? This way is the same command but `a la tcolorbox` style. If you insist with `\label`, you can use it inside title option, but the reference is just the box number without the section component. Another solution could be to use a `\newtcbtheorem` where labels are automatically created and you don't use `\label` at all.

Comment: after i created ```\newtcolorbox``` i want to use ```\label{}``` when i create a box ```\begin{mybox}\label{}```, and the ```\ref``` seems not the box number,  how can i format it?

Comment: what is the option to set so that all numbering are within the current tcolorbox?