# How to define labels within a tcolorbox?

Tags: environments, tcolorbox

Inspired by [this great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124848/30658), I'm trying to typeset my definitions using `tcolorbox`. My document contains hundreds of definitions which follow the pattern:

```
\begin{definition}
% ...
\label{something:meaningful}
\end{definition}
```

My problem is that I haven't found a way to define a `definition` environment based on `tcolorbox` where the labels work as expect. To demonstrate the problem, I have created a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage[paperheight=100in]{geometry} % just to allow taking a screen shot...
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

% this is my current "definition" environment
\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=chapter]{definition}{
  enhanced,
  breakable,
  fonttitle=\sc,
  title={Definition \thetcbcounter}
}
\let\clearpage\relax % also to allow a screenshot

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{Section 1}
\begin{definition}
A first definition. Labeled \texttt{def:A}.
\label{def:A}
\end{definition}

\section{Section 2}
\begin{definition}
Another definition. Labeled \texttt{def:B}.
\label{def:B}
\end{definition}

\subsection{With a Subsection}
\begin{definition}
Another definition -- this time nested. Labeled \texttt{def:C}.
\label{def:C}
\end{definition}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\begin{definition}
Definition in the second chapter. Labeled \texttt{def:D}.
\label{def:D}
\end{definition}

Judging from the definition headers, it looks like the per-chapter-counter seems to work.
But lets see what happens if we reference the definitions.
\begin{itemize}
  \item \texttt{\textbackslash ref\{def:A\}} refers to Definition \ref{def:A}.
  \item \texttt{\textbackslash ref\{def:B\}} refers to Definition \ref{def:B}.
  \item \texttt{\textbackslash ref\{def:C\}} refers to Definition \ref{def:C}.
  \item \texttt{\textbackslash ref\{def:D\}} refers to Definition \ref{def:D}.
\end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

So I'm using an auto-counter on a per chapter basis. This counter itself also seem to work, since the header of my definitions have a correct per-chapter numbering. The problem is that referring to the labels does not give the same number. This is the output of the above MWE:

[image: output]

In fact it looks like the labels simply refer to the surrounding chapter/section. Is there a way to make the labels consistent with the definition number?

I have discovered that there is an optional `label` argument for environments defined by `newtcolorbox`. However, I haven't found a way to use it in my case. I guess it only works for environments that have a mandatory argument, and I don't want to break compatibility to all my existing definitions following the above pattern.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `label` key for the `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

% this is my current "definition" environment
\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=chapter]{definition}[1][]{
  enhanced,
  breakable,
  fonttitle=\scshape,
  title={Definition \thetcbcounter},
  #1
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{Section 1}
\begin{definition}[label=def:A]
A first definition. Labeled \texttt{def:A}.
\end{definition}

\section{Section 2}
\begin{definition}[label=def:B]
Another definition. Labeled \texttt{def:B}.
\end{definition}

\subsection{Whit a Subsection}
\begin{definition}[label=def:C]
Another definition -- this time nested. Labeled \texttt{def:C}.
\end{definition}

\chapter{Second Section}
\begin{definition}[label=def:D]
Definition in the second chapter. Labeled \texttt{def:D}.
\end{definition}

Judging from the definition headers, it looks like the per-chapter-counter seems to work.
But lets see what happens if we reference the definitions.
\begin{itemize}
  \item \texttt{\textbackslash ref\{def:A\}} refers to Definition \ref{def:A}.
  \item \texttt{\textbackslash ref\{def:B\}} refers to Definition \ref{def:B}.
  \item \texttt{\textbackslash ref\{def:C\}} refers to Definition \ref{def:C}.
  \item \texttt{\textbackslash ref\{def:D\}} refers to Definition \ref{def:D}.
\end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

[image]

In my example, I used

```
\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=chapter]{definition}[1][]{
  enhanced,
  breakable,
  fonttitle=\scshape,
  title={Definition \thetcbcounter},
  #1
}
```

so the label has to be passed as an optional argument:

```
\begin{definition}[label=<text>]
...
\end{definition}
```

but you could also say

```
\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=chapter]{definition}[1][]{
  enhanced,
  breakable,
  fonttitle=\scshape,
  title={Definition \thetcbcounter},
  label=#1
}
```

and then simply

```
\begin{definition}[<text>]
...
\end{definition}
```

Or you could make this a mandatory argument.

### Remark

The `theorems` library from `tcolorbox` allows one to use

```
\newtcbtheorem[<init options>]{<name>}{<display name>}{<options>}{<prefix>}
```

and then

```
\begin{name}{}{<label>}
...
\end{name}
```

so one can say `\ref{<prefix:<label>}` to get cross-references. I didn't use this in the answer linked in the question since there no numbering (so no cross-referencing) was required.

Comment: Hm, this means that I have to edit hundreds of definitions. There is no way to automate this to keep my existing use patterns?

Comment: @bluenote10 I'll have to look at the code to see how `tcolorbox` handles the labels internally, but this will have to wait. Perhaps, in the meantime, someone else will provide a better alternative.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. I'm glad to have any solution at all. The reason why I didn't use `newcbtheorem` in the first place was just that I was trying to avoid refactoring all definitions/labels.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina This does not allow you to use `\nameref` with the correct name-the value of the title key, however. Is this correct? It did not work with my test. Maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to make `\label` work inside a `tcolorbox` – but this is *really dirty* and only works under the assumption, that the `\label` command immediately follows the `\begin{definition}` command!

It works by "catching" the `\label` token using `xparse`s `t` argument. To use `xparse` we have to create the environment by hand and not by the means of the `theorem` library.

An advantage of this ugly hack is the fact, that the autocomplete features of some tex(t)-editors should be able to find the labels defined this way, whereas the ones created with `[label=def:test]` will not be found – at least "out-of-the-box".

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{xparse,skins,breakable}

\tcbset{%
    basestyle/.style={enhanced,breakable,
        fonttitle=\scshape,
        coltitle=white},
    defstyle/.style={basestyle,colback=red!10!white},
    theostyle/.style={basestyle,colback=blue!10!white},
}
\DeclareTColorBox[auto counter,number within=section,crefname={definition}{definitions}]{definition}{ o O{} t\label g }{%
    defstyle,IfValueTF={#1}{title={Definition~\thetcbcounter\ (#1)}}{title=Definition~\thetcbcounter}, IfBooleanTF={#3}{label=#4}{},#2}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}[My title]\label{def:test}
    Foo.
\end{definition}

This was \cref{def:test}.
Unlabeled definition:

\begin{definition}[Cool Title][colback=orange!10!white]
    Just a test.
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Hey Jannes ^^, bin auf das gleiche Problem gestoßen: Die `tcolorbox` hat einfach einen echt nicht sehr kompatiblen Syntax für Theoreme, *kopf-schüttel*. Jo nette Lösung! :)

Answer (score 2):

PLEASE consider using @Gonzola's answer as it is the appropriate way to proceed. A text editor that provides a good *regular expressions* functionality should allow you to patch your document in a single "search and replace" type of manner.

I have attempted to use the `number freestyle` option for `\newtcolorbox` as described in the package documentation, but even this does not seem to work, so I am guessing there is a bug in the `tcolorbox` package (how the reference is defined?)... but this is purely speculative.

Nonetheless, here is a terrible solution that will work. To apply this to your current document, you will simply have to **search** for every occurence of `\label{def:` and **replace** it with `\addtocounter{definition}{-1}\refstepcounter{definition}\label{def:`.

With this code, the labels will remain consistent whether or not you define a `\label`in **every** definition.

The code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage[paperheight=100in]{geometry} % just to allow taking a screen shot...
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

%% Create a new counter that will follow tcolorbox's numbering
\newcounter{definition}[chapter]
\renewcommand*{\thedefinition}{\noexpand\thechapter.\noexpand\arabic{definition}}

% this is my current "definition" environment
\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=chapter]{definition}{
  enhanced,
  breakable,
  fonttitle=\sc,
  title={Definition \thetcbcounter\refstepcounter{definition}}
}
\let\clearpage\relax % also to allow a screenshot

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{Section 1}
\begin{definition}
A first definition. Labeled \texttt{def:A}.
\addtocounter{definition}{-1}\refstepcounter{definition}\label{def:A}
\end{definition}

\section{Section 2}
\begin{definition}
Another definition. Labeled \texttt{def:B}.
\addtocounter{definition}{-1}\refstepcounter{definition}\label{def:B}
\end{definition}

\subsection{Definition without label}
\begin{definition}
Another definition -- this time without label.
\end{definition}

\subsection{Whit a Subsection}
\begin{definition}
Another definition -- this time nested. Labeled \texttt{def:C}.
\addtocounter{definition}{-1}\refstepcounter{definition}\label{def:C}
\end{definition}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\begin{definition}
Definition in the second chapter. Labeled \texttt{def:D}.
\addtocounter{definition}{-1}\refstepcounter{definition}\label{def:D}
\end{definition}

Judging from the definition headers, it looks like the per-chapter-counter seems to work.
But lets see what happens if we reference the definitions.
\begin{itemize}
  \item \texttt{\textbackslash ref\{def:A\}} refers to Definition \ref{def:A}.
  \item \texttt{\textbackslash ref\{def:B\}} refers to Definition \ref{def:B}.
  \item \texttt{\textbackslash ref\{def:C\}} refers to Definition \ref{def:C}.
  \item \texttt{\textbackslash ref\{def:D\}} refers to Definition \ref{def:D}.
\end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: As a sidenote, both `\noexpand`s aren't necessary in the `\thedefinition` redefinition: they are simply relics of tests I was conducting with the `number freestyle` option for `\newtcolorbox`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work. The idea is that if you have defined an environment `⟨name⟩` with `\newtcbtheorem[⟨init options⟩]{⟨name⟩}{⟨display name⟩}{⟨options⟩}{⟨prefix⟩}`, e.g. `\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{definitiontcb}{Definition}{}{def}`, then you can use `\newtcbtheoremautolabelaux[⟨name2⟩]{⟨name⟩}{⟨prefix⟩}`, e.g. `\newtcbtheoremautolabelaux[definitiontcbautolabel]{definitiontcb}{def}`, to get a new environment `⟨name2⟩` that grabs the label in its body and gives it as an argument to `⟨name⟩`, i.e. `\begin{⟨name2⟩}{#1}...\label{⟨label⟩}...\end{⟨name2⟩}` is equivalent to `\begin{⟨name⟩}{#1}{⟨label⟩}......\end{⟨name⟩}`.

If you never need to use tcb environments directly, and always want the autolabel variant, you can simply rename `\newtcbtheorem` to `\newtcbtheoremautolabel`: the command `\newtcbtheoremautolabel[⟨init options⟩][⟨name⟩]{⟨name2⟩}{⟨display name⟩}{⟨options⟩}{⟨prefix⟩}` has the same interface as `\newtcbtheorem` (with an extra optional argument for the name of the intermediate tcb environment).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{proof-at-the-end}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{xparse}


\ExplSyntaxOn

% \gobble:n just discards its argument
\cs_new:Npn \gobble:n #1 {}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_blank_p:n {V}
\tl_new:N\tl_head
\tl_new:N\tl_tail
\tl_new:N\tl_beforetail
\tl_const:Nn \tl_just_label {\label}

% \extract_label:NN \tl_body \tl_label
% removes \label{⟨label⟩} from \tl_body and stores ⟨label⟩ in \tl_label
\cs_new:Npn \extract_label:NN #1 #2 {
  \tl_if_in:NnTF #1 {\label} {% Some \label: replace it by gobble:n in #1 and store its argument in #2
    \tl_set_eq:NN\tl_tail#1
    \bool_do_until:nn{% Search for the \label token
      \tl_if_eq_p:NN\tl_head\tl_just_label% || \tl_if_blank_p:V\tl_tail
    }{
      \tl_set:Nx\tl_head{\tl_head:N\tl_tail}
      \tl_set:Nx\tl_tail{\tl_tail:N\tl_tail}
    }
    % At this point, tl_head is \label, and tl_tail is whatever is after it
    \tl_set:Nx\tl_head{\tl_head:N\tl_tail}
    % At this point, tl_head is the (potential) argument of \label
    \tl_if_blank:VTF\tl_tail{
      \ERROR
    } {
      \tl_set_eq:NN #2 \tl_head
      \tl_replace_once:Nnn #1 {\label} {\gobble:n}
    }
  } {% No \label: leave #1 as is and make #2 empty
    \tl_clear:N #2
  }
}

\exp_args_generate:n {Nnnf}
\tl_new:N\tl_body
\tl_new:N\tl_label

% After calling
% \newtcbtheorem[⟨init options⟩]{⟨name⟩}{⟨display name⟩}{⟨options⟩}{⟨prefix⟩}
% and
% \newtcbtheoremautolabelaux[⟨name2⟩]{⟨name⟩}{⟨prefix⟩}
% the environment ⟨name2⟩ is defined such that \begin{⟨name2⟩}{#1}...\label{⟨label⟩}...\end{⟨name2⟩}
% behaves like
% \begin{⟨name⟩}{#1}{⟨label⟩}......\end{⟨name⟩}
% By default, ⟨name2⟩ = ⟨name⟩autolabel
\NewDocumentCommand{\newtcbtheoremautolabelaux}{omm}{
  \NewDocumentEnvironment{\IfNoValueTF{#1}{#2autolabel}{#1}}{mb}{% ##1 = title, ##2 = body
    % decompose the body ##2 into the label \tl_label and the rest tl_body
    \tl_set:Nn\tl_body{##2}%
    \extract_label:NN\tl_body\tl_label
    % remove the prefix #3 from \tl_label
    \tl_set:Nx\tl_label{\tl_range:Nnn \tl_label { \tl_count:n{#3} + 2 } { -1 }}
    % Call the #2 environment with the expected arguments
    \exp_args:NnnV\begin{#2}{##1}\tl_label
      \tl_use:N\tl_body%
    \end{#2}%
  }{}
}

% \newtcbtheoremautolabel[⟨init options⟩][⟨name⟩]{⟨name2⟩}{⟨display name⟩}{⟨options⟩}{⟨prefix⟩}
% is just
% \newtcbtheorem[⟨init options⟩]{⟨name⟩}{⟨display name⟩}{⟨options⟩}{⟨prefix⟩}
% followed by
% \newtcbtheoremautolabelaux[⟨name2⟩]{⟨name⟩}{⟨prefix⟩}
% with ⟨name⟩ = ⟨name2⟩auxnoautolabel by default
\NewDocumentCommand{\newtcbtheoremautolabel}{O{}ommmm}{
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{
    \newtcbtheorem[#1]{#3auxnoautolabel}{#4}{#5}{#6}
    \newtcbtheoremautolabelaux[#3]{#3auxnoautolabel}{#6}
  }{
    \newtcbtheorem[#1]{#2}{#4}{#5}{#6}
    \newtcbtheoremautolabelaux[#3]{#2}{#6}
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{definitiontcb}{Definition}{}{def}
\newtcbtheoremautolabelaux[definitiontcbautolabel]{definitiontcb}{def}

% Or both combined:
%\newtcbtheoremautolabel[number within=section]{definitiontcbautolabel}{Definition}{}{def}

% Since the title is an optional argument for amsthm, I prefer using a definition that matches that
% (I switched from using \NewEnviron to \NewDocumentEnvironment in \newtcbtheoremautolabelaux because otherwise this did not work)
\newenvironment{definition}[1][]{%
  \begin{definitiontcbautolabel}{#1}%
}{%
  \end{definitiontcbautolabel}%
}%


\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{Section 1}

\begin{definition}
A first definition. Labeled \texttt{def:A}.
\label{def:A}
\end{definition}

\section{Section 2}
\begin{definition}
Another definition. Labeled \texttt{def:B}.
\label{def:B}
\end{definition}

\subsection{With a Subsection}
\begin{definition}
Another definition -- this time nested. Labeled \texttt{def:C}.
\label{def:C}
\end{definition}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\begin{definition}
Definition in the second chapter. Labeled \texttt{def:D}.
\label{def:D}
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}
Definition in the second chapter. Labeled \texttt{def:E}.
\label{def:E}
\end{definition}

Judging from the definition headers, it looks like the per-chapter-counter seems to work.
But lets see what happens if we reference the definitions.
\begin{itemize}
  \item \texttt{\textbackslash ref\{def:A\}} refers to Definition \ref{def:A}.
  \item \texttt{\textbackslash ref\{def:B\}} refers to Definition \ref{def:B}.
  \item \texttt{\textbackslash ref\{def:C\}} refers to Definition \ref{def:C}.
  \item \texttt{\textbackslash ref\{def:D\}} refers to Definition \ref{def:D}.
  \item \texttt{\textbackslash ref\{def:E\}} refers to Definition \ref{def:E}.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```