# Not able to cross-reference theorem in latex

Tags: cross-referencing

I am trying to crossreference theorem or definition but the code is not working. The code is given below. Pease help me in this.

Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[justified, twoside]{tufte-book} % Use the tufte-book class which in turn uses the tufte-common class

\usepackage{booktabs} % Better horizontal rules in tables

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{mparhack}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,parskip}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[english]{babel} %%% 'french', 'german', 'spanish', 'danish', etc.
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{todonotes} 
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{caption}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}%New package added to this file

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx, float} % Needed to insert images into the document


\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\usepackage{etoolbox}


\tcbuselibrary{xparse,skins,breakable}

%Defining Chapter Outline in tcolorbox
\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{chapteroutline}[2][]{
  enhanced,
  breakable,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colback=white!90!yellow, colframe=red!50!blue,
  fonttitle=\sc,
  title={\textbf{\begin{Large}CHAPTER OUTLINE\end{Large} }}
}
\let\clearpage\relax % also to allow a screenshot{}




%Defining definition in tcolorbox
\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=chapter]{definition}[2][]{
  enhanced,
  breakable,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colback=white!90!yellow, colframe=black!50!blue,
  fonttitle=\sc,
  title={\textbf{Definition  ~\thetcbcounter: #1}}
}
\let\clearpage\relax % also to allow a screenshot{}



%definiting Theorem in tcolorbox
\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=chapter]{theorem}[2][]{
  enhanced,
  breakable,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colback=green!2!white, colframe=black!45!green,
  fonttitle=\sc,
  title={Theorem  ~\thetcbcounter: #1}
}
\let\clearpage\relax % also to allow a screenshot{}


%definiting Formulla in tcolorbox
\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=chapter]{formulla}[2][]{
  enhanced,
  breakable,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colback=green!2!white, colframe=red!45!green,
  fonttitle=\sc,
  title={Formulla  ~\thetcbcounter: #1}
}
\let\clearpage\relax % also to allow a screenshot{}


%definiting Remark in tcolorbox
\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=chapter]{remark}[2][]{
  enhanced,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colback=green!0!white, colframe=black!45!white,
  fonttitle=\sc, attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2mm,xshift=-3mm},
  title={Remark  ~\thetcbcounter: #1} 
}
\let\clearpage\relax % also to allow a screenshot{}

%definiting Example in tcolorbox
\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=chapter]{example}[2][]{
  enhanced,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colback=white!0!white, colframe=yellow!90!white,
  fonttitle=\sc, attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2mm,xshift=-3mm},
  title={Example  ~\thetcbcounter: #1} 
}
\let\clearpage\relax % also to allow a screenshot{}



% chapter format
\titleformat{\chapter}%
  {\Huge\rmfamily\itshape\color{red}}% format applied to label+text
  {\llap{\colorbox{red}{\parbox{1.5cm}{\hfill\itshape\huge\color{white}\thechapter}}}}% label
  {2pt}% horizontal separation between label and title body
  {}% before the title body
  []% after the title body
  
% section format
\titleformat{\section}%
  {\normalfont\Large\itshape\color{orange}}% format applied to label+text
  {\llap{\colorbox{orange}{\parbox{1.5cm}{\hfill\color{white}\thesection}}}}% label
  {1em}% horizontal separation between label and title body
  {}% before the title body
  []% after the title body
  
% subsection format
\titleformat{\subsection}%
  {\normalfont\large\itshape\color{blue}}% format applied to label+text
  {\llap{\colorbox{blue}{\parbox{1.5cm}{\hfill\color{white}\thesubsection}}}}% label
  {1em}% horizontal separation between label and title body
  {}% before the title body
  []% after the title body

% paragraf format
\titleformat{\paragraph}%
  {\normalfont\Large\itshape\color{red}}% format applied to label+text
  {\llap{\colorbox{orange}{\parbox{1.5cm}{\hfill\color{blue}\thesection}}}}% label
  {1em}% horizontal separation between label and title body
  {}% before the title body
  []% after the title body  
 


% definition format
\titleformat{\defn}%
  {\normalfont\Large\itshape\color{orange}}% format applied to label+text
  {\llap{\colorbox{orange}{\parbox{1.5cm}{\hfill\color{white}\thesection}}}}% label
  {1em}% horizontal separation between label and title body
  {}% before the title body
  []% after the title body
  
 
\DeclareMathOperator{\sech}{sech}
\DeclareMathOperator{\cs}{cosec}
\DeclareMathOperator{\csh}{cosech}


\usepackage{xspace} % Used for printing a trailing space better than using a tilde (~) using the \xspace command

\newcommand{\hlred}[1]{\textcolor{Maroon}{#1}} % Print text in maroon

\newcommand{\hairsp}{\hspace{1pt}} % Command to print a very short space
\newcommand{\ie}{\textit{i.\hairsp{}e.}\xspace} % Command to print i.e.
\newcommand{\eg}{\textit{e.\hairsp{}g.}\xspace} % Command to print e.g.


\newcommand{\docmsg}[2]{\bigskip\begin{fullwidth}\noindent\ttfamily#1\end{fullwidth}\medskip\par\noindent#2}


\usepackage{makeidx} % Used to generate the index
\makeindex % Generate the index which is printed at the end of the document

\pgfplotsset{my style/.append style={axis x line =middle, axis y line=middle, xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, axis equal}}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Rolle's Theorem]\label{th:rolls}

Let $f:[a, b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function satisfying the following conditions:
\begin{enumerate}
\item $f(x)$ is continuous on the closed interval $[a,b].$
\item $f(x)$ is differentiable on the open interval $(a,b)$.
\item $f(a)=f(b).$\\
Then there exists atleast one number $c$ such that $a<c<b$ and 
$f^{\prime}(c)=0.$
In other words $f(x)$ has a critical point in $(a,b)$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

\ref{th:rolls}

\begin{example}\label{ex:01}

Verify Rolle's Theorem for $f(x)$, where
\[f\left(x\right)=8 x -x^{2}~~~\text{in}~~[0,8]\] 
\end{example}
\ref{ex:01}

\end{document}
```

Comment: please remove everything not required to show your problem. It isn't reasonable to have a test file using so many packages. Also note you have `\let\clearpage\relax ` in more than one place. That will completely break latex and make it quite likely that the document does not terminate and you get no pdf output at all. (it isn't clear why you have this more than once as the first one has already changed the meaning for the entire document)

Comment: Sir, there is actually much more text which I have not included as I want to learn only how to cross-reference the theorem and example, that's why I have included only theorem and example in the problem. However I have included all the premables.

Comment: See [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231375/how-to-define-labels-within-a-tcolorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231375/how-to-define-labels-within-a-tcolorbox)

Comment: including all the preamble is what I meant. You are asking people to debug  your code and including _thousands_ of lines of code unrelated to your question, I ran your example and it produces no output at all, so hard to address the question "cross reference not working"