# Is it possible to use \label with tcbtheorem?

Tags: tcolorbox, theorems, labels

I would like to simply update my preamble to use tcolorbox for theorems without needing to manually remove the `\label{}` found after every `\begin{theorem}` or to replace the optional argument corresponding to the title. That is, I would like my theorem environment to look like

```latex
\begin{theorem}[optional title]\label{optional label}
Theorem text.
\end{theorem}
```

while still using the `tcolorbox` theorem from the `Theorem` library. Is there a way this can be done?

Edit: here is an MWE.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem[
    auto counter,
    number within=section,
    ]{theorem}{Theorem}{
    colback=gray!25,
    colframe=gray!90!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries}{thm}


\begin{document}
    \begin{theorem}{tcb label style}{works}
        Can cite \ref{thm:works}.
    \end{theorem}

    \begin{theorem}{default label style}{}
        \label{thm:doesntwork}
        Can cite \ref{thm:doesntwork}.
    \end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

which outputs [image: output of \label in tcbtheorem]

Additionally, whatever mechanism my text editor uses to autosuggest labels when writing `\ref` and such does not work with the `\begin{theorem}{title}{label}` method provided by tcolorbox.

Edit 2: the following works but is not ideal.

```latex
\newtheoremstyle{tcb-drop-in-thm}% 〈name〉
                {}% 〈Space above〉1
                {}% 〈Space below 〉1
                {}% 〈Body font〉
                {}% 〈Indent amount〉2
                {\bfseries\color{white}}% 〈Theorem head font〉
                {}% 〈Punctuation after theorem head 〉
                {\newline}% 〈Space after theorem head 〉3
                {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ $\blacktriangleright$ #3}}% 〈Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’ )〉
\theoremstyle{tcb-drop-in-thm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins, breakable}
\tcolorboxenvironment{theorem}{%
    colback=gray!25,
    colframe=gray!90!black,
    enhanced,
    top=0mm,
    overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
        \fill[gray!90!black] (frame.north west)rectangle ([yshift=-5mm]frame.north east);
            \end{tcbclipinterior}}
}
\begin{document}                                                                 
    \begin{theorem}                                                              
        \label{thm:test}                                                         
        test can be referenced as \ref{thm:test}                                 
    \end{theorem}                                                                
\end{document}
```

which outputs[image]

Comment: You can use `\label` more or less anywhere. Please provide a small complete document that shows whatever problem you are having.

Comment: Thank you David. I have updated with an MWE.

Comment: oh OK, but if switching to tcb you need to add that `{}` argument anyway so why not add the label at that point? you can't simply keep the syntax from amsthm or whatever unless I am missing something?

Comment: May be this answer helps: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/392161/1952

Comment: Thank you Ignasi, that does help but is a bit messy. I am currently trying to wrap the amsthm's environments in color boxes and create a new `\theoremstyle` that will look like what I want. It is not quite working as expected yet.

David, I do not know if there is a way to keep the syntax, but that is primarily what I need right now. Many of my collaborators forget the updated tcb syntax, and I can also use this as a sort of "drop-in replacement" for the style without breaking anything. Additionally, the label autosuggestions in my text editor only work when labels are placed in a `\label`.