# Combine mdframed, xparse and cleveref

Tags: mdframed, cleveref, xparse

Inspired by this post: 
[Typesetting a definition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124847/typesetting-a-definition), I wanted to define some fancy theorem-like environments.

Contrary to the examples given in this post, I need a definition environment
with a counter and an optional title, so I used xparse.

Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools, isomath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newcommand{\thedefinition}{\arabic{theorem}}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{definition}{o}{%
    \refstepcounter{theorem}
    \begin{mdframed}[%
        singleextra={
            \node[
                overlay,
                anchor=west,
                xshift=7pt,
                fill=gray,
                rounded corners=2pt,
            draw] at (P-|O) {\bfseries
                \IfValueTF{#1}{%
                    Definition~\thedefinition~(#1)
                }{%
                    Definition~\thedefinition
                }
            };
        },
        firstextra={
            \node[
                overlay,
                anchor=west,
                xshift=7pt,
                fill=gray,
                rounded corners=2pt,
            draw] at (P-|O) {\bfseries
                \IfValueTF{#1}{%
                    Definition~\thedefinition~(#1)
                }{%
                    Definition~\thedefinition
                }
            };
        },
    ]
}{%
    \end{mdframed}
}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod

\begin{definition}[Optional]
    \label{defi}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
\end{definition}

\cref{defi}
\end{document}
```

I erased some part of the style, so don't worry about that.

My problem is the last line with `cref`, it gives `theorem 1` and not
`definition 1` which is normal because I didn't do anything to change that. I
found some answers instructing to use `crefalias` or the `aliascnt` package, but i
didn't succeed in using them. Any help would be appreciated.

PS: If you have some advices to simplify the code, I'll be happy to take them.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use a new counter? Or a new theorem type? Right now, you are not really using `amsthm` at all that I can see. All you get from it is a `\newcounter{theorem}`.

Comment: @cfr I have multiple environments that I want numbered with the same counter. The definition environment is supposed to act like a new theorem type, so i don't really understand what you mean by "Or a new theorem".

Comment: You will cause readers much confusion if you say `theorem 3` when there is not `theorem 2` just because there was a `definition 2`. If they are of different kinds then they get different labels and different counters. If not, they they get a single name (`definition` *or* `theorem` *or*...) and a single counter. But I'm not sure I've understood what you are doing.

Comment: It's a common practice in some journals to use the same counter. This way when you want to look for `definition 22` you don't need to look for the closest `definition`. You just look to the current counter (of the page you're reading) and you know where to go from there ;)

Comment: In that case, I suggest you look at `fancyref` as an alternative to `cleverref`. I don't use `cleverref` myself, but `fancyref` can definitely do what you want easily. `cleverref` I suspect only with difficulty, if at all. It is designed to figure out the right label automatically. If it is getting it wrong, that is not so good. `fancyref` doesn't try to figure it out for itself. Hence, you won't have the same problem.

Comment: Apparently my language isn't supported, I have to use cleveref.

Comment: You want `\crefname{theorem}{definition}{definitions}`

Comment: @clemens But won't that change it for all things counted using the `theorem` counter?

Comment: @cfr oh, so the OP wants theorems *and* definitions *sharing a common counter*?

Comment: @clemens yes. If I define the definition environment with a simple `\newtheorem`, I can have the desired result. It's the usage of mdframed that makes that difficult

Comment: @clemens That's how I understood 'I have multiple environments that I want numbered with the same counter. ' in [this comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254774/combine-mdframed-xparse-and-cleveref?noredirect=1#comment609150_254774).

Comment: I must be blind but I can read that nowhere in the question… :( Anyway, then the OP just needs to use `\label[definition]{defi}` inside of the `definition` environment

Comment: You can provide the necessary language support for `fancyref` if you really want to. However, it may just be easier to say `definition \ref{defi}` unless there's a clever solution out there.  This is kind of why I don't use `cleverref` although I'm not using a common counter as far as readers are concerned but only so far as TeX is concerned. (I use, say, `enumerate` but might use `\label{qn:qn1)` to get `question 1`.)

Comment: @clemens Thats why I included a link to the relevant *comment* which appears as [this comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254774/combine-mdframed-xparse-and-cleveref?noredirect=1#comment609150_254774) in [my comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254774/combine-mdframed-xparse-and-cleveref?noredirect=1#comment609293_254774) ;).

Comment: @cfr I *must* be blind! I overread this... Time for coffee :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood this correctly you want both theorems and definitions sharing the same counter but want use different names with `cleveref` when referring to on or the other? In this case it should suffice to give the type as optional argument in the `definition` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{mathtools, isomath}
\RequirePackage{amsthm}
\RequirePackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newcommand{\thedefinition}{\arabic{theorem}}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{definition}{o}{%
    \refstepcounter{theorem}
    \begin{mdframed}[%
        singleextra={
            \node[
                overlay,
                anchor=west,
                xshift=7pt,
                fill=gray,
                rounded corners=2pt,
            draw] at (P-|O) {\bfseries
                \IfValueTF{#1}{%
                    Definition~\thedefinition~(#1)
                }{%
                    Definition~\thedefinition
                }
            };
        },
        firstextra={
            \node[
                overlay,
                anchor=west,
                xshift=7pt,
                fill=gray,
                rounded corners=2pt,
            draw] at (P-|O) {\bfseries
                \IfValueTF{#1}{%
                    Definition~\thedefinition~(#1)
                }{%
                    Definition~\thedefinition
                }
            };
        },
    ]
}{%
    \end{mdframed}
}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod

\begin{definition}[Optional]
    \label[definition]{defi}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
\end{definition}

\Cref{defi} and \cref{foo}

\begin{theorem}\label{foo}
  foo bar
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A more automised solution uses the `aliascnt` package:

```
\usepackage{aliascnt}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newaliascnt{definition}{theorem}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{definition}{o}{%
    \refstepcounter{definition}
```

Then the optional argument of `\label` is not necessary.

I take it the definition of the `definition` environment is still a draft (the result can surely not be what you want)? Do you have a reason for using `\RequirePackage` instead of `\usepackage`?

Comment: I erased some part of the definition to not clutter the question (but you're right that's not the final version). `RequirePackage` was just a copy/paste error, I'll fix that in my question. Thanks for the answer, I'll wait a little bit (I really don't wanna change all my labels), if nothing comes up, I'll accept your anwser.

Comment: @Zii8roZi then see my edit: there is an automated solution