# how to draw a vertical line in text

Tags: article

I'm trying to draw a vertical line similar to the one use in the  abstract of [this document](https://www.latextypesetting.com/examples/bank_report/bank_report_latex.pdf), as seen below 
[image]

I didn't find any good solution so far.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124847/108724

Comment: Welcome to TeX - LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem and early trials. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.``

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin Hi, Alessandro. I have seen that the pdf of the user is a template of Overleaf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use or `mdframed` package (or `tcolorbox`) to create the vertical bar. Here there is a short example. Obviously, this code is only a starting point that can be expanded: arrange colours, insert italics, line spacing, font size, etc. The font used is [tgpagella](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/texgyrepagella/):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[linewidth=1.5,linecolor=red, topline=false,rightline=false,bottomline=false]
\textbf{\textcolor{red}{Abstract}} \textit{\small \lipsum[1]}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum by comment of the user @Caladay:** `mdframed` has differents options: you put

```
innertopmargin=-.1em, innerbottommargin=0em
```

and with the parameter `-.1em` (decrease) the lenght of the vertical red line. With `0em` the bottom vertical red line is aligned. With `-.1em` it is a bit lower. However you can choose your best lenght.

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[linewidth=1.5,linecolor=red, innertopmargin=-.1em, innerbottommargin=0em, topline=false, rightline=false,bottomline=false]
\textbf{\textcolor{red}{Abstract}} \textit{\small \lipsum[1]}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Sebastiano, thank you very much for your reply. I would like to be able to define how long is the line (it seems too long). Moreover I'm looking to have the abstract starting with a leftskip.  I used the below code without success: `
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begingroup
\leftskip=1cm 
\begin{mdframed}[linewidth=1.5,linecolor=red, topline=false,rightline=false,bottomline=false]
\textbf{\color{red} Abstract} :\textit{ \lipsum[1] }
\end{mdframed}
\endgroup

\section{Introduction}   
\lipsum[1]`

Comment: @Caladay Very kind Caladay I have read now your comment and I have put an addendum. You advice me for further requests and you read if my answer is clear. My best regards.

Comment: Dear Sebastiano, thank you very much. It works like a charm. I added another option ( leftmargin=1em) to have it shifted to the left. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Caladay If the suggestion gave by `Sebastiano` suits with your requirement, then you have to click the `tick` mark, this is the best way you show your tribute ....please...

Comment: @Mady Yuvi Thank you for your comment, I followed your recommendation

Comment: @MadyYuvi ahahah...don't worry for the check mark :-))) you are very kind with me. As you are older you notice that you are increasingly more wise and, at least for me, the objective is to help. Here we are a great group and excellent users both from a human and sensitive point of view like you. Thank you.

Comment: @Caladay Very very good :-) for the use of leftmargin=1em.